# node-fetch not working but axios is working fine

Tags: node.js, api, axios, node-fetch

I have an express server on localhost from which I am making an Api call

```
function get(){
    console.log('calling get')

    fetch('https://www.nseindia.com/api/marketStatus')
    .then(val=>{console.log(val)})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

}

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
    get()
});
```

the output which I get with using node-fetch is the following and It doesn't throw any kind of an error. It doesn't go inside then or the catch callback.

```
Listening on Port 3000
calling get
```

but with axios the code inside the then callback runs fine

```
function get(){
    console.log('calling get')

    axios.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/marketStatus').then(val=>{
         console.log(val)
     }).catch(error => {
         console.log(error)
     })

}

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
    get()
});
```

any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems odd. maybe instead of `console.log(val)` try `console.log('test')`

Comment: no, still not printing test.